# How to optimize inserting 12K of JSON into database using PHP or Mysql or Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I'm quite new to this, but I have the code below working great, it pulls in the json, loops and inserts them into database, whilst checking if the player exists, if exists then update ONLY score and bonus. If a new player then insert the new row.

My problem is the list of players I have is huge around 10-15K (players1 to players15000). When I am monitoring Laravel query logs for potential performance hogs, I notice the sheer amount of queries being ran because of the foreach looping the query one by one.

Since all the 10-15K data is there and available from the $scores variable.
Is there any way to get it to run one big query, rather than 10-15K individual queries whilst being protected by the PDO placeholder?

I was thinking about building an array in PHP and then feed the array to Mysql query, but then how would you protect it with placeholders?
Plus this would be ran a few times a day

I'm really confused how to best do this, so here is the code, the original is much larger as it contains teams, location, ip address etc and so forth. But this is a trimmed down example

```
Unique key in database set as (id)

$scores = '
{
   "1":{
      "id":"1",
      "player":"1",
      "name":"James",
      "score":"10.25",
      "bonus":"2.10"
   },
   "2":{
      "id":"2",
      "player":"2",
      "name":"John",
      "score":"11.50",
      "bonus":"1.10"
   }
}';

$decoded = json_decode($scores);

foreach($decoded AS $value)
{
    $update = DB::insert("INSERT INTO players (id,player,name,score,bonus) VALUES (:id,:player,:name,:score,:bonus) 
                            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score=VALUES(score), bonus=VALUES(bonus)",
                            array(
                                ':id' => ,$value->id
                                ':player' => ,$value->player
                                ':name' => ,$value->name
                                ':score' => ,$value->score
                                ':bonus' => ,$value->bonus
                            )
                        );
}
```

Comment: `INSERT` statements support multiple `VALUES` blocks, so you should be able to build 1 query to insert (say) 20 records. Since you're using parameterised queries, it may require variable names with a number at the end... `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (:id1,:player1,:name1,:score1,:bonus1) (:id1,:player2,:name2,:score2,:bonus2)` etc... Failing that, you'll probably find that bulk inserting from the command line on the sql server will be orders of magnitude faster, since it cuts out the network hop and you can do larger bulk inserts (assuming you can get the data onto the machine)

Comment: These won't be updated by me, so I need a solution where they can update via php, Is there any limitation on how large or long the query can be? As there will be 10K-15K rows worth of data?

Comment: I would try a couple of things... 1) wrap the _foreach_ loop in a _transaction_. That way you only have one 'commit'. 2) move 'insert' query outside the loop and 'prepare' it once. Inside the 'loop' 'bindValue' and 'execute'. This reduces the 'sql parse' down to once. It may be quick enough at this point.

Comment: @adamgouldie Yes, there definitely are limits, but they're not set in stone. It's been quite a while since I used MySQL but I remember having issues trying to run a 20MB script remotely. IIRC, the issue was due to the configured input buffer size in MySQL. It was fixable but in the end we just SCP'd the script and ran it locally. As an aside, don't assume the config will be the same on your dev and production servers, as prod has usually been hardened/had limits tightened.

Comment: blimmin hell, Ryan Vincent you were right, placeholders were causing me a headache, kept on getting array to string conversion error and code was getting extrememly messy building the arrays with placeholders. As soon as I attempted the transaction option, the time it took to run dropped by almost 3/4. I think i'll settle with that. Thanks

Comment: @adamgouldie,  Thanks - you can always try any other changes to further optimize it later if required.

Answer (score 0):

well for start, your INSERT can look like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(col1, col2) VALUES(val1, val2), (val1, val2)
```

That is one INSERT which is inserting 2 rows, and it's faster than 2 INSERTs

As for laravel, you can use insert function as shown [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#inserts) (see 'Inserting Multiple Records Into A Table')

Not sure how it works behind the scenes tho, my guess is faster than foreach

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did try reasearch Laravel but couldn't find any solution to INSERT and UPDATE certain fields like the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Supposedly one doesn't exist. Therefore I had to resort to using MYSQL method. The code looks good, but I would like them to be parametized for prevention against SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very fast way (other than your IODKU loop, or @Basic batching of it).

1. Batch `INSERT` all the data into a temp table.  (A la @Traxo answer.)
2. Copy over the 'new' rows:  `INSERT INTO real SELECT ... FROM tmp LEFT JOIN real ON ... WHERE ... IS NULL`
3. Update the existing rows:  `UPDATE real JOIN tmp ON ... SET real.bonus = tmp.bonus, real.score = bonus.score;`

There are some details, such as `BEGIN`...`COMMIT` assuming you are using InnoDB (which you should be).

If your periodic update is really a total replacement, then do it this way:

1. `CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;`
2. Load `new`
3. `RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;` -- atomic and instantaneous
4. `DROP TABLE old;`

Comment: Hi Rick, does this not mean that you first have to create loops to get the values of the JSON formatted properly to do the batch insert. Secondly if you want placeholders for protection against SQL injection, you then have to build another set of loops to format the placeholders. So the real issue is not on the SQL side, but more how to process the JSON into a format that is a one SQL query.

Comment: In your original post, `$value->score` (etc) need to be escaped to pervent SQL ingestion.  JSON, itself, is free of injection problems (I think).  The escaping can be in the same loop as where you are building the batched `INSERT` or IODKU or whatever.  Performance issues:  escaping is trivial overhead; batching of inserts can speed up the process 10-fold.